# Why can we do Tashlich until Hoshana Rabba

Tags: minhag, calendar, rosh-hashanah-new-year, tashlich

One of the reasons to do Tashlich, according to Chabad.org is: "Another reason for saying Tashlich next to a river is because Rosh Hashanah is the day when we coronate G‑d as King of the Universe. Jewish kings are anointed next to rivers, and so it is appropriate that we crown G‑d as our King next to a river, as well."

If this is the case then why can Tashlich be done until Hoshana Rabba?

Comment: Because there are other reasons

Answer (score 3):

In the past I typed up a few ideas on Tashlich and in it I bring sources on until when one can say it . See footnotes as well.

[image]